# "WordPress attack protection CAPTCHA. Enter username: t48if Password: The result of math 30+2"

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and I've build website in my localhost with it, After I migrated to my hosting server.
front-end loading fine but while trying to load admin page it's showing like that
"A username and password are being requested by http://lore4u.byethost24.com.
The site says: "WordPress attack protection CAPTCHA. Enter username: t48if Password: The result of math 30+2"

How can I fix?
any one help me

Comment: your site will face additionnal automatic impersonalisation for spam spreading. And even more since you posted the url on public sites ( like this SO post) keeping the CAPTCHA is one of the line of defence against that. i strongly suggest you to keep it.

Comment: This CAPTCHA protection seems not very efficient if there is only one question, i tested it and got very same question !

Comment: What exactly do you want to be helped with?
Do you want to remove permanently the this pop-out window?

Answer (score 0):

ITS A TRICK QUESTION!

Here's the solution: make one "space" on username field.. (so it's blank)
and type the digit answer into the password field..
so if the math is 1+5 the answer to type would be "6" without ""..

username:
password: 6

then it will redirect you to the official wordpress login :)